# Як перекласти Strider?

Tags: переклад, from-english, from-russian

Російською це буде "Бродяга" або "Странник". Який український аналог цих двох слів? Я знайшов варіант "Блукач", але він не всім подобається.

Найближче за смисловим контекстом до цього Арагорн з трилогії "Володар кілець".
[Aragorn was a Ranger of the North, first introduced with the name Strider at Bree, as the Hobbits continued to call him throughout The Lord of the Rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aragorn)

Або взагалі Еней. Не по характеру, а по пригодам.

Річ у тім, що це назва роману, який складається з чотирьох частин, кожна з яких має назву на зразок першої "Наівний пілігрим". Тобто скрізь обігруються варіанти якраз "мандрівника" або "подорожнього". Палітра слів повинна передавати зміну стану головного героя. Тому відтінок кожного слова дуже важливий.

Comment: Можливо можна перекласти як [ходак](http://sum.in.ua/s/khodak), але без контексту важко щось сказати.

Comment: Aragorn was a Ranger of the North, first introduced with the name Strider at Bree, as the Hobbits continued to call him throughout The Lord of the Rings. Арагорн з володаря кілець підходить найкраще по контексту. Тому я так поставив запитання.

Comment: У перекладі "Володаря перснів" Олени Фешовець, що був надрукований видавництвом "Астролябія", псевдонім Арагорна перекладений як "Бурлака".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Російсько-український словник 1930р. (О. Ізюмов)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&scope=all&highlight=on)**

> Странник – ***мандрі́вник***

**Словарь української мови 1909р. (Б. Грінченко)**

> ***Мандріве́ць***, -вця́, м. Странникъ; путешественникъ.
> ***Проча́нин***, -на, м. Богомолець; странникъ. *Куди, прочане, ви йдете?* Котл. Ен. І. 16. *Над вечір увійшли ми в село, і розбрелись
> прочане улицями. МВ. І. 17.*

СУМ-11

> ***[Мандрівник](http://sum.in.ua/s/mandrivnyk)*** Той, хто мандрує; подорожній, подорожанин. //  Людина,
> що за характером своєї діяльності мусить часто мандрувати.

[Словник синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)

> ***МАНДРІ́ВНИ́К*** (той, хто мандрує, подорожує), МАНДРІВЕ́ЦЬ, ПОДОРО́ЖНІЙ, ПОДОРОЖА́НИН, ПОДОРО́ЖНИК *розм.*, ОБХОДИ́СВІТ
> *розм.*,СТРА́ННИК *заст.*, ВОЯЖЕ́Р *заст. ірон.*, **ПІЛІГРИ́М** *книжн*. заст.,ВАНДРІ́ВНИ́К діал.,ВАНДРІ́ВЕЦЬ *діал.*

СУМ-11

> ***[Пілігрим](http://sum.in.ua/s/pilighrym)*** 1. Паломник. *Пілігрими, що йдуть до святих місць, підкоряються темному покликові забобонності* (Павло Загребельний,
> Шепіт, 1966, 27); *Воліла б вона бути похованою романтично.. Щоб ішли
> тоді до неї, романтичної таврійської святої, вродливі молоді
> пілігрими* (Олесь Гончар, Таврія, 1952, 131);  *У порівняннях. Іду я з
> посохом, як пілігрим, Дорогою тернистою, крутою* (Микола Терещенко,
> Дорога, 1939, 36).
> 2. *перен. **Мандрівник, подорожній***. *Призвичаївся [М. Гоголь] відчувати під ногами хистку палубу, І.. йому все здавалося, що й
> земля, і камінь ходять під ним — блідим, жовтим, виснаженим бурями й
> громами пілігримом* (Олексій Полторацький, Повість.., 1960, 395).

На мою думку, для назви книги краще використати один із синонімів до слова ***"мандрівник"***, а саме ***"пілігрим"***.

Comment: Дякую за детальну відповідь. Є один момент. "Бродяга" - назва книги російською, а "Наивный пилигрим" - назва першої частини. Друга, наприклад, "Измученый путник". Тому відтінки важливі, а пілігрім вже зайнято в назві частини. До речі, "Змучений мандрівник" підійде для перекладу назви другої частини.

Answer (score 3):

Дуже віддалені синоніми:

- [Блукач](http://sum.in.ua/s/blukach).
- [Бурлака](http://sum.in.ua/s/burlaka).
- [Галайда](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghalajda).
- [Заволока](http://sum.in.ua/s/zavoloka).
- [Прочанин](http://sum.in.ua/s/prochanyn) — навіяне *пілігримом*, але я не певен, що підходить, бо, на відміну від *пілігрима*, що має два значення («паломник» і «подорожній»), здається, має лише одне («паломник»).
- [Путник](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom4.pdf#page=642) — це подається як діалектне.
- [Скитальник](http://sum.in.ua/s/skytaljnyk).
- [Ходак](http://sum.in.ua/s/khodak), [ходок](http://sum.in.ua/s/khodok).
- Шляхоходець — якщо підійде неологізм.

Answer (score 2):

> stride
>
> 1. Іти великими кроками, рішуче, поспішаючи, нетерпеливо, гонорливо.
> 2. Зробити великий крок.
> 3. Широко розставляти ноги.

Отже, важливо вказати на тип ходи. Він не просто блукач чи путник. Він іде швидко, впевнено, переконливо, знаючи куди і навіщо. Він **стрімкохід**.

Comment: Цією відповіддю ви примусили мене замислитись, що мій головний герой все ж таки не зовсім Арагорн. Тому що мій персонаж в першій книзі багато блукає по волі обставин. Можливо - Еней? Але дякую за цей варіант. Щоправда він не милозвучний дещо.

Answer (score 0):

Можу запропонувати варіанти "Мандрівник" чи "Пілігрим".

Comment: Дуже дякую за надану відповідь. І я згоден, що ці слова є доречними перекладами слів _strider/бродяга/странник_ (принаймні в певних контекстах). Але річ у тім, що у відповідях на цьому сайті прийнято посилатися на джерела, щоби читач завжди мав змогу перевірити хід думок автора відповіді. У Вашому випадку це можуть бути, наприклад, якісь англійсько-українські словники (для _strider_ чи _stride_), російсько-українські словники (для _бродяга_, _странник_, _бродить_ тощо), словники синонімів, вже перекладена література з цими словами або якісь комбінації з вищезазначеного.

Comment: …Чи принаймні хоч якісь матеріали, що хоч якось обґрунтовують/підкріплюють хід Ваших думок.

Comment: Дякую. Річ у тім, що це назва роману, який складається з чотирьох частин, кожна з яких має назву на зразок першої "Наівний пілігрим". Тобто скрізь обігрується варіпнти якраз "мандрівника". Тому відтінок дуже важливий.